# Parsing (reading) prettytable text tables

Tags: python, parsing, prettytable

I couldn't find any information about reading ascii tables (prettytable-looking).
I need to parse some tables that look like this:

```
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|               Planets               |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
| Planet | R (km) | mass (x 10^29 kg) |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|  Sun   | 696000 |    1989100000     |
|(Solar) |        |                   |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
| Earth  |  6371  |      5973.6       |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|  Moon  |  1737  |       73.5        |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|  Mars  |  3390  |      641.85       |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
```

As you can see, this table contains heading and subtitle, but it isn't a main problem.
Here how I tried to parse it (all tries was in Python, maybe exist more suitable language):

- `module petl` - doesn't work, coud not read `+--------+--------+-------------------+`
- `np.fromtxt` or smth doesnt work too, because there's no array
- `module asciitable` doesn't work,

```
asciitable.read("sample.txt",delimiter='|',guess=False,numpy=False, quotechar="'")
InconsistentTableError: Number of header columns (1) inconsistent with data columns (9) at data line 0
Header values: ['+----------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------+']
```

and of course I tried all the combinations of parametrs

- And yes, tried simple (but not) way and used regular expressions. But in case if "row" have more than 1 line there's too hard to catch all exceptions.
- Also tried simple `split`, but it unhappy way too...

I heard about numpy substitute by 0 and 1, but its too hard with my table. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do this using python, with a few passes you can convert this into something that suits your needs.

```py
table_str = """
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|               Planets               |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
| Planet | R (km) | mass (x 10^29 kg) |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|  Sun   | 696000 |    1989100000     |
|(Solar) |        |                   |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
| Earth  |  6371  |      5973.6       |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|  Moon  |  1737  |       73.5        |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|  Mars  |  3390  |      641.85       |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
"""

table_list = [
    [item.strip() for item in line.split('|') if item]  # maintain the number of columns in rows.
    for line in table_str.strip().split('\n')
    if '+-' not in line  # discard +-
]

column_count = len(table_list[1])
row_idx_to_remove = list()
for row_idx, row in enumerate(table_list[2:], start=2):
    if any(not c for c in row):  # A multiline column entry
        row_idx_to_remove.append(row_idx)
        for col_idx, col in enumerate(table_list[row_idx - 1]):
            table_list[row_idx - 1][col_idx] += row[col_idx]

# Remove the rows that have already been merged into previous ones.
for idx in row_idx_to_remove:
    del table_list[idx]

table_dict = {'Name': table_list[0][0], 'Column Names': table_list[1], 'Rows': table_list[2:]}

print(table_dict)
print(table_list)
```

Output:

```py
{'Name': 'Planets', 'Column Names': ['Planet', 'R (km)', 'mass (x 10^29 kg)'], 'Rows': [['Sun(Solar)', '696000', '1989100000'], ['Earth', '6371', '5973.6'], ['Moon', '1737', '73.5'], ['Mars', '3390', '641.85']]}
[['Planets'], ['Planet', 'R (km)', 'mass (x 10^29 kg)'], ['Sun(Solar)', '696000', '1989100000'], ['Earth', '6371', '5973.6'], ['Moon', '1737', '73.5'], ['Mars', '3390', '641.85']]
```

This implementation does not handle empty columns in rows nor does it handle the case where every column in a row has more than one line.

You could also make it use re.split, and split on lines containing +-, then you could handle any rows that would contain the edge cases of this implementation.

Edit:
Here is an implementation that uses re.split:

```
import re


def parse_ascii_table(ascii_table):
    table_re_list = re.split(r'\+[+-]+', ascii_table)
    table_list = [l.strip().replace('\n', '') for l in table_re_list if l.strip()]
    table = {'Title': table_list[0].replace('|', '').strip(),
             'Column Names': [ch.strip() for ch in table_list[1].split('|') if ch.strip()],
             'Rows': list()}
    for row in table_list[2:]:
        joined_row = ['' for _ in range(len(row))]
        for lines in [line for line in row.split('||')]:
            line_part = [i.strip() for i in lines.split('|') if i]
            joined_row = [i + j for i, j in zip(joined_row, line_part)]
        table['Rows'].append(joined_row)
    return table


table_str = """
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|               Planets               |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
| Planet | R (km) | mass (x 10^29 kg) |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|  Sun   | 696000 |    1989100000     |
|(Solar) |        |                   |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
| Earth  |  6371  |      5973.6       |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|  Moon  |  1737  |       73.5        |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|  Mars  |  3390  |      641.85       |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
"""
print(parse_ascii_table(table_str))
```

Output:

```
{'Title': 'Planets', 'Column Names': ['Planet', 'R (km)', 'mass (x 10^29 kg)'], 'Rows': [['Sun(Solar)', '696000', '1989100000'], ['Earth', '6371', '5973.6'], ['Moon', '1737', '73.5'], ['Mars', '3390', '641.85']]}
```

Comment: Okay, you're trully genius! But there's something to fix... What is `for idx in row_idx_to_remove:
    del table_list[idx]`? maybe `table_list.pop(index)`? But it doesn't work too...
And so it reads only every 2n lines: first, third, fifth etc

Comment: So, I am running this in python3.6. This for loop should remove the rows that contain the multiline column entries (in this case the `(Solar)` part which has already been added to the first line of that entry in the previous for loop). What happens when you run it? Is there an error on that statement?

Comment: Of course there's an error. `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`.

Comment: I am not sure why you say of course there's an error.
Did you copy paste the whole code into a file and run it? Did you modify it? What version of python are you running?
Here is a link to the code in an online interpreter: https://www.online-python.com/72vj6wOeA5

Comment: I'm so sorry that say rude! I mean of course I have an error while try to do it like you. I didn't modify your code, just try another table (where more than 1 row has 2 more lines). And idk but first 2 rows are joining as one. I use Python 3.7

Comment: Ah, yeah, this is a naive implementation. I added another that uses re.split. Although I did it through my phone, so hopefully it is good enough to work for you. At least ypu could modify it to work to your needs.

Comment: Finally, no doubt that you’re genius! But I solve first variant by reversing list: `for idx in row_idx_to_remove[::-1]: table_list.pop(idx) ` and that works perfectly. It was because when element in list deleted, next element replace it. Soon I’ll try the variant with re, and in future make an unique library that parse harder tables with combined headers. I won’t forget to mention you if it all works out!

Comment: Nice, happy it worked out. Good luck.

Comment: Dear friend, can you help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71262590/parse-ascii-table-header) question?